# How to assign a view to a tab bar item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Basic question -

I'm adding a tab bar item to my tabbarcontroller. It's going to be a view.

I feel really dumb for asking this, but…how do you assign the view you want to load for the tab bar item?

"When I click this tab, load this view."

Using Xcode4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add a tab bar item directly. Instead, drag out a UIViewController from the Library onto the tab bar. This will create a new bar item for you, with a UIViewController. Select the UIViewController itself, and on the Identity tab set the class to your view controller, and on the Attributes tab specify the name of the nib file to load.

Comment: Ok - that last part is the part I can find in the Xcode GUI. Where can you specify a "nib name?" I see where to specify it in the attribute tab, but do I name the "xib" file I named something special? Naming it the file name doesn't appear to work. I have to say - I find this GUI they have a little obtuse.

Comment: [Figured this out]
Something important to note: I didn't have the nib file name specified correctly. And, in addition, on the tab controller you need to adjust the tab item's class to the new name of the files owner class of the viewcontroller. This stuff all makes sense from an OOP perspective, but can be difficult if you're not used to the GUI.